# Looking at characters of folder name and moving to different location

Tags: batch-file, tags, character, filenames

When I find a folder beginning with the letters ABCDE, I need to copy it to another location. Here is what I have been doing already but using a specific folder name i.e. (ECU). In the first part I am also zipping any folder with the name "Logfile".

So to recap, instead of moving everything inside C:\ECU, I instead need to move everything inside the folder starting with ABCDE. Apologies for being so long winded!

I take it i would need to put some sort of if statment in the line before xcopy to check if the first five characters of the folder are ABCDE??

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

```
@echo off 
for /d /r "c:\ecu" %%a in (Logfile*) do ( 
  if /i "%%~nxa"=="Logfile" ( 
     pushd "%%a" 
     REM zip all files in the backup directory 
     FOR %%A IN (.TXT .cpi) DO "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -r "%%~nA.zip" "%%A" 
     FOR %%A IN (*.TXT *.cpi) DO DEL "%%A" 
     popd 
  ) 
)

@echo All logfiles zipped. Press Enter to move Project to backup? 
pause > nul

xcopy /s "C:\ECU" "C:\Complete"

rename "C:\Complete" %Date:~-10,2%%Date:~-7,2%%Date:~-4,4%

pause
```

Comment: You wrote `I instead need to move everything` <--- do you need to move or copy the folders?

Comment: I need to find a folder with the first five characters showing as ABCDE for example. I then need to copy this folder and its contents to another location.

Comment: Is it just the one folder then?

Comment: It is a folder with sub folders inside. Example  C:\ECU with four folders inside ECU1, ECU2", ECU3 and ECU4.

Comment: I have this code to look at the first five characters of the foldername but cant seem to get it to return true

Answer (score 0):

@echo off

set foldername=C:\Test\Test2\ABCDEFGHI 
call :GetFolderName5 "%foldername%"

:GetFolderName5 
set folder5chr=%~n1 
set folder5chr=%~dp1%folder5chr:~0,5% 
echo.%folder5chr%

IF %folder5chr% == "ABCDE" ( 
@echo Yes 
) ELSE ( 
@echo No 
) 
pause